# Android emulator queues clicks?

Tags: java, android

The problem i'm facing at the moment is that the android emulator seems to queue the clicks i do on the button below. If i click in a regular speed, it's no problem what so ever. But whenever i so to say, spam-click the button, it seems that it recieves all clicks and does that number of operations.

Example:
The array is 5 values long, if i stand on index 5 and click on the backbutton 4 times very fast, i end up at index 1, but if i stand at index 2 and spam-clicks three times, it throws
`java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

code as follows:

```
     ButtonGoBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(View view) {
             // here i set it disabled to prevent mass clicks/taps/touches. 
             ButtonGoBack.setEnabled(false);


             enumCounter--;



             temporaryValue = values[enumCounter];

             doSomething(temporaryValue);
              // hides button              
              if(enumCounter== 0)
              {
                  ButtonGoBack.setVisibility(4);
              }


           }

       });
```

100~ or so code-lines after.

```
ButtonGoBack.setEnabled(true);
```

does not seem to do the trick.

any suggestions how to do this in a different manner?

Comment: if i understand correctly you want your button to click only when the previous click operation is finished and all clicks that happen before that need to be ignored?

Comment: Please use setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE) instead of setVisibility(4). Always use defined, human-readable constants, it increases code readability by a lot and is a good coding style. I just had to check what 4 is in the docs. People who may be able to answer might not do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by surrounding with `try{}catch{}` and incrementing the counter by one.

```
  ButtonGoBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(View view) {

                try
                {                             
                 enumCounter--;

                 temporaryValue = values[enumCounter];

                 doSomething(temporaryValue);
                  // hides button              
                  if(enumCounter== 0)
                  {
                      ButtonGoBack.setVisibility(4);
                  }
                 } 
                 catch(Exception e)
                 {
                   ButtonGoBack.setVisibility(4);
                   enumCounter++;          
                 }
               }        
           });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to start from the last after reaching 0 you can

```
enumCounter--;
 if(enumCounter<0) enumCounter=4;
         temporaryValue = values[enumCounter];
         doSomething(temporaryValue);
```